# How to get file size of http file path

Tags: java

I'm using the below code to download files from a remote location via http.  Some assets are not fully downloading and appear to be corrupt.  It looks to be about 5% of the time.  I'm thinking it'd be good to ensure I've downloaded the full file by getting the file size in advance and comparing it to what I've downloaded to be sure nothing was missed.

Through some google searches and looking at the objects I'm already working with I don't see an obvious way to obtain this file size.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
file = new File(destinationPath+"."+remoteFile.getExtension());

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
   bos.write(i);
}
bos.flush();
bis.close();
```

Comment: It should be specified in the "Content-length" header for http transfers. But it depends on the web server you are querying. Anyway, not sure how to retrieve headers in java.

Comment: Its available via the *Content-Length* header which the target server may or may not set (connection.getHeaderField())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`con.getContentLength()` *may* give you what you want, but only if the server provided it as a response header.  If the server used ["chunked" encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) instead of providing a Content-Length header then the total length is not available up-front.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `getContentLength()` method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) `HttpURLConnection` that inherits from `URLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**InputStream#available()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) method.

It returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.

The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(destinationPath+"."+remoteFile.getExtension());
System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "+ fis.available());
```

Comment: Quoted from the javadoc you linked to: "Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream." - it gives you simply a guaranteed minumum number of bytes you could read without blocking (which may be zero), not necessarily the total number of bytes that the stream will _ever_ be able to give you.